# .htaccess is loading index.php for any website link

Tags: .htaccess

I have a .htaccess code in a core php application. htaccess code is loading home page which is index.php on every other pages i have on my website which is about,services,blog and contact page. My .htaccess file code is below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
```

Let me know what is wrong with this code. I wrote this for removing index.php from url as well as removing .php extension from end of every link i have on my website. You can check below link for better understanding of issue.

http://codinghash.in/DWP/contact

Above link is loading homepage(index.php)

What i want to do?

I want to achieve SEO friendly pretty url's as below.

http://codinghash.in/DWP/index.php ( Redirect it to http://codinghash.in/DWP/)
http://codinghash.in/DWP/xyz.php ( Redirect it to http://codinghash.in/DWP/xyz)

Comment: What do you think this is doing?  The first rule changed `/DWP/contact` to `/index.php/DWP/contact`, but the second condition is not looking for those entities in that order.  It's looking for `/DWP/contact/index.php`.

Comment: I know i'm doing it wrong but what is the correct htaccess code to achieve my need?

Comment: Isn't that backwards?  You want `/DWP/xyz` to redirect to `/DWP/xyz.php`, and `/DWP/` to `/DWP/index.php`, right?